# CRM 365 Business Rules Deactivated but still running on forms?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, business-rules, dynamics-crm-365

I am in the process of re-writing the Business rules for our CRM Installing on Office 365. The problem is, the old ones I have decided to turn off due too the changes that are taking place on the new versions of the form.

However, when I deactivate the business rules the fields that were effected by the rules, are still effected.

The fields even know that the rules have been deactivated but continue to run.
I have also cleared my browser cache and used different machines so I'm pretty sure its not a client machine problem.

EDIT:
For security reasons I can't share the names of the business rules but I have attached an image to show they are deactivated.
[image]

In the design view of the form, for example there are these 3 fields:
[image]
However in the live view this is displayed:
[image]

Comment: Are you certain there is no other component running? e.g. workflow, business rule, plugin, JavaScript?

Comment: can you add some context like logic inside rule, screenshot, etc?

Comment: @ArunVinoth i have edited accordingly.

Comment: @JamesWood i recently removed two JS libraries that were running on the form, however these are definitely not running now because the Dialogs would open or i would get a script error if so.

Comment: Did you check the tab/section Properties in Form editor (designer view) - if it’s unchecked visible by default (where these controls are placed)?

Comment: May be even the controls (textbox, picklist) could be unchecked visible by default for form loading performance, Verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if "Visible by default" is unchecked for Tab/Section/Controls, that may be the reason why its hidden.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling your business rule, you have to click on the "save" button. This is tricky. If you only disable it, you will get a message saying that the business rule is disabled, you also see the status of "disabled", but it is actually still running. As soon as you click in "save", the business rule stops running.

[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30611624)